# How do I use a single object that only changes a single property?

Tags: terraform, datadog

Say I have these local properties:

```
locals {
   http_headers = {
          Accept        = "blabla"
          Content-Type  = "blabla"
          Authorization = "Bearer {{ token_in_test }}"
   }
}
```

I have 3 different environments to test in: test, sims and production. I have secrets already assigned to each token value for each environment and they're called  `token_in_test`, `token_in_sims`, `token_in_prod`.

My modules for example is:

```
module "http_sims" {
  url = "https://blabla.com/blabla"
  headers = local.http_headers
}
```

How do I shift around the headers value so that the `http_headers.authorization` can pick different tokens for different environments? I have 1 object for http_header_test but the token is not valid for sims environment.

What I've done so far is make 3 different object in local for each environment. But surely there is a better way to make 1 object and just change the Authorization value and assign it to a token for the desired environment. Is there a way I could do this?

Comment: Are you using terraform workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you've shown in the `Authorization` value isn't Terraform template syntax so I'm assuming your goal is to generate a template for some other system to evaluate, and so your requirement is just to interpolate a different template variable name into those braces depending on the environment.

To do this you'll need to have the appropriate variable name available in some other input variable or output value in this module. Assuming it were an input variable directly then it might look like this:

```
variable "bearer_token_secret_name" {
  type = string

  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("^\\w+$", var.bearer_token_secret_name)
    error_message = "Must be one or more ASCII letters, digits, or underscores."
  }
}

locals {
  http_headers = {
    Accept        = "blabla"
    Content-Type  = "blabla"
    Authorization = "Bearer {{ ${var.bearer_token_secret_name} }}"
  }
}
```

This uses [Terraform's own template interpolation syntax](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#string-templates), starting with `${`, to insert the provided name into the `Authorization` attribute value.

I included a `validation` block on the input variable to ensure that the given string cannot include characters that would make the resulting string not be a valid template for whatever underlying system is actually going to be inserting the real bearer token.

---

If you already have an input variable for choosing an environment and instead want to make the template name be an implementation detail of your module, here's a different variant which selects the variable name based on a lookup table:

```
variable "environment" {
  type = string

  validation {
    condition     = contains(["sims", "test", "production"])
    error_message = "Must be a valid environment name."
  }
}

locals {
  bearer_token_secret_names = tomap({
    sims       = "token_for_sims"
    test       = "token_for_test"
    production = "token_for_prod"
  })

   http_headers = {
     Accept        = "blabla"
     Content-Type  = "blabla"
     Authorization = "Bearer {{ ${local.bearer_token_secret_names[var.environment]} }}"
   }
}
```

Again a validation rule on the input variable makes sure that it will always match one of the entries in the lookup table, so this should always generate a valid template or return an error to the user of the module saying that their chosen environment name wasn't valid.